# Sumar input text en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, validación, algoritmos

Supongamos que tengo lo siguiente:

```
<body data-ng-init="getTotal()">
<input type="number" ng-change="getTotal()" ng-model="factor.inputs[0]"
ng-value="30"/>
<input type="number" ng-change="getTotal()" ng-model="factor.inputs[1]"
ng-value="20" />
<input type="number" ng-change="getTotal()" ng-model="factor.inputs[2]"
ng-value="60" />
{{total}}
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="disabledSave" value="Save" />
```

appcontroller.js

```
      $scope.factor = { inputs: [] };
      $scope.getTotal = function() {    
          $scope.disabledSave = false;
          var total = 0;

          for(var i = 0; i < $scope.factor.inputs.length; i++){
              var numero = $scope.factor.inputs[i] || 0;                  
              total = total + numero;
          }

          if (total > 100) {
              $scope.disabledSave = true;
          }
      };
```

Entra a la función pero no me sale el total, que en este caso es 110, creo que el problema esta en :  `$scope.factor = { inputs: [] };`

Comment: con "puedo tener N input number" te refieresa a que no solo hay 3 campos de numeros si no que puede haber muchos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero si estas ocupando `Angularjs`, aplicalo. Si puedes tener "n" inputs lo mejor que puedes hacer es definir la cantidad de input en el controlador.

En este caso declare `$scope.fields` que contiene un arreglo llamado `inputs`, como primera instancia esta vacio. Luego declaro la funcion `$scope.addInput` que lo que hace es agregar `''` y porque? En la vista tengo un `ng-repeat` de mi arreglo `fields` pero dentro de un `input` por lo tanto agregar inputs constantemente. Finalmente agrego el evento `ng-change` a la funcion `getTotal` que recorri mi arreglo `fields` y obtiene el valor ingresado. Si el valor de la suma es mayor a 100 como dijiste, el boton `Save` queda disabled.

```
$scope.fields = { inputs: [] };
$scope.addInput = function() {
  $scope.fields.inputs.push('');
}
$scope.ver_boton = true;
$scope.getTotal = function(){
  $scope.total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.fields.inputs.length; i++){
    var numero = Number($scope.fields.inputs[i] || 0);
    $scope.total = $scope.total + numero;
  }
  if($scope.total > 100){
     $scope.ver_boton = false;
  }else{
    $scope.ver_boton = true;
  }
}



<input ng-repeat="input in fields.inputs track by $index" type='number' ng-model='fields.inputs[$index]' placeholder='Ingrese numero' ng-change="getTotal();">
<button ng-click="addInput()">Add input</button>
<button ng-click="" ng-disabled="!ver_boton">Save</button>
```

[Codepen para ver el ejemplo funcionando](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/ENPxrQ)

**EDICION**

Ya que aplicaste gran parte de mi codigo pero como dices "No me sale el total", es porque el total no es `$scope.total` si no `var total`, cambia `total` a `$scope.total`

Para que se agregue y vea en primera instancia agrega a tu vista `Total: {{total || 0}}`

```
    $scope.factor = { inputs: [] };
    $scope.getTotal = function() {
        $scope.disabledSave = false;
        $scope.total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.factor.inputs.length; i++) {
            var numero = $scope.factor.inputs[i] || 0;
            $scope.total = $scope.total + numero;
        }

        if ($scope.total > 100) {
            $scope.disabledSave = true;
        }
    };
```

**EDICION 2**

Como tu otro problema es inicializar un input con un `ng-model` no deberias ocupar `ng-value` por ningun motivo.

```
$scope.fields = { inputs: [] };
$scope.fields.inputs[0] = 30;
$scope.fields.inputs[1] = 80;
```

Para ver inmediatamente el resultado una vez cargada la vista, debajo de tu funcion `getTotal();` debes llamarla.

```
$scope.ver_boton = true;
$scope.getTotal = function(){
  $scope.total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.fields.inputs.length; i++){
    var numero = Number($scope.fields.inputs[i] || 0);
    $scope.total = $scope.total + numero;
  }
  if($scope.total > 100){
     $scope.ver_boton = false;
  }else{
    $scope.ver_boton = true;
  }
}
$scope.getTotal();
```

Comment: No era exactamente lo que queria pero me ha servido de guia. Thanks

Comment: que querias exactamente entonces? No era conseguir la suma y hacer que se bloqueara el boton? @Jose

Comment: en principio lo tengo, pero imaginate que tengo exactamente ya esto en la vista:

Comment: @Jose puedes explicar entonces cual es el error en tu codigo?

Comment: he modificado la pregunta principal, siento pero no se muy bien como funcioan esto de overflow, soy nuevo

Comment: @Jose ya te deje la solucion en la edicion de mi respuesta

Comment: mira esto : http://codepen.io/sirdaiz/pen/LbGaBd, aquí no me sale el total ni los valores de los input

Comment: A mi si me sale....

Comment: te sale si modifica el valor de algun input, pero incialmente al cargar no sale el total

Comment: @Jose ya lo actualice, debes agregar a tu vista `Total: {{total || 0}}`

Comment: claro si pongo eso sale 0, pero yo he inicializado los input con valores y no los esta sumando

Comment: ng-value no existe para inputs del tipo `number` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: lo cambio en el editor por text y aun asi el total sigue siendo 0

Comment: @Jose La edite nuevamente, probada en tu mismo codepen. Si no sabes mucho de Angularjs te invito a estudiarlo un poco antes de preguntar y decir "no funciona" solo porque no funciona. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, en mi codepen no me aparece que hayas modificado nada, tb comentarte que en tu edicion 2 estas inicializando en el .js los valores de factor.inputs y yo tengo que coger los valores de la vista y no puedo inicializarlos en el js, de todas formas muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: La logica de angularjs es trabajar con modelos. Los modelos estan definidos e inicializados en el controlador . Si quieres modificar ese valor se hace desde la vista y esto se ve reflejado inmediatamente en el controlador. Si quieres trabajar como trabaja un html normal con javascript normal, creo que no deberias implementar angularjs si no vas a ocuparlo como corresponde. Saludos

Comment: http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/ENPxrQ mi codepen modificado y funcionando!...

Comment: Al final yo lo solvente, lo que he hecho es inicializar los valores como tu lo haces. Un saludo y nuevamente gracias

Comment: @Jose saludos tambien! recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta si te sirvio con el fin de que otros usuarios aprovechen la solucion.